# JAR file won't run when double clicked but runs in terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a JAR file that outputs something onto the terminal when run.
However, when I double click the JAR file, nothing happens, and my Mac tells me to check the console for possible errors, and I find nothing.

On the other hand, running the JAR from terminal `java -jar file.jar` works just fine, and the JAR runs as expected.

I am using IntelliJ to build my JAR, and I am sure that my configurations are correct for building a JAR file.

Comment: Sounds like your `jar` file type association is **not** set up.

Comment: @ernest_k No, my Mac, by default, opens any .jar file using "Jar Launcher (15.0.1)".

Comment: Dunno, if it's even supposed to work the wikipedia page of Jar Launcher sais "Java programs without any GUI should be run from the command line as they may not properly execute without a pseudo terminal.".

Comment: If the only thing your jar does is writing to `System.out`,  you will not see a thing when double-clicking. Is that the case? No console is automatically opened.

Comment: @JoopEggen No console is opened, but I forgot to mention that I prompt the user for input using `new Scanner(System.in)` later on. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a shell-script to launch your application. Call it `something.sh` and put `java -jar YourProgram.jar` in it. SH scripts you should be able to double click. Java files you cannot (if they don't have an UI) as they are not launched by a terminal and the JVM does not know witch terminal to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is not a problem about your system but your application. Did you include any instructions for the application to stop or pause? Because what could be happening is that it executes your program but it goes so fast that you dont even have time to see it. Try using Thread.Sleep(500).

(those 500 are miliseconds so feel free to change the value)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also prompt user input later on using `new Scanner(System.in)`, but thanks for the answer.